# I want to install openresty in my ubuntu

Tags: installation

I had downloaded ngx_openresty-1.2.6.6.tar.gz (stable release) from http://openresty.org/
and I followed these commands on terminal:

```
tar xzvf ngx_openresty-VERSION.tar.gz
cd ngx_openresty-VERSION/
./configure --with-luajit
make
make install
```

But I am not able to install it in my computer. I assume that make install command doesn't works out, because it prompts me error when I go with `make install`.

Please let out the way to get openresty installed on Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you aware that VERSION is the software version? So the commands should be: `tar xzvf ngx_openresty-1.2.6.6.tar.gz` and `cd ngx_openresty-1.2.6.6/`.

Comment: ya i did with tar xzvf ngx_openresty-1.2.6.6.tar.gz and cd ngx_openresty-1.2.6.6 and even then i was not able to install

Comment: Then please edit your question and include the 10 last lines printed by `configure` and `make`.

Answer (score 0):

before configure step:

```
apt-get -y update
apt-get -y install libreadline-dev libncurses5-dev libpcre3-dev libssl-dev perl make
```